# directory creation problem

Tags: directory, home-directory, paths

What is the meaning of the following statement : I want to install math system named GAP.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/lib/gap4r5': Permission denied
Cannot create directory /usr/local/lib/gap4r5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating it using `sudo`.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/gap4r5
```

That should work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it gives this massage

Comment: [sudo] password for ...

Comment: Just enter your password, same one you use to login to the machine.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. but when I give my password, it is not written ?

Comment: should usr be changed to my name during setting? I mean that usr/local/lib must be changed into chia/local/lib?

Comment: No `usr` not to be changed, and the password will not show when typing.

Comment: I recieved the following errors:

Comment: Creating directory: /usr/local/lib/gap4r5
mkdir: cannot create directory `local': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `local': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `bin': Permission denied
./gapsync: line 120: local/bin/binpath: No such file or directory
Calling: /usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete --port 8731 --exclude=local/ rsync.gap-system.org::gap4r5/ .

Comment: permision denied (13) means what?

Comment: and lots of other things like:

Comment: sud mkdir /usr/local/bin
./gapsync: line 59: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
./gapsync: line 66: [: too many arguments
Going to syncronize GAP in: sud mkdir /usr/local/lib/gap4r5/gap4r5